# Dropshadow UserControl

Tags: wpf, controls

I think doing the following is probably pretty common:

```
<Grid>
    <Border>
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>

    <SomeControl/>
</Grid>
```

Ok, I did that without the aid of the ide which I am admittedly lost without so forgive me if I forgot something but I think you get the point.

My question is, would it be possible to create a UserControl that would allow me to do this instead:

```
<DropShadowBorder>
    <SomeControl/>
</DropShadowBorder>
```

If so, please do tell how.

EDIT:  Just in case it's not immediately obvious, the point here is that I would usually put a border around my control but when I want to use a drop shadow I can't because I only want the border to have a drop shadow and not everything in it.  So instead I have to create the border separately in the same grid space, but this is annoying because when I adjust margins and such on my control I have to go duplicate those changes on the border each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a user control (user control cannot have a content). You will have to create a custom control. I suggest you to create a custom control that derives from `ContentControl`.

The code of the custom control (default code !):

```
public class DropShadowBorder : ContentControl
{
    static DropShadowBorder()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DropShadowBorder), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DropShadowBorder)));
    }
}
```

Then define a default style for your control (in `generic.xaml`)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DropShadowBorder}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DropShadowBorder}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect />
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Border>

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```